# Custom Tab Bar in Xcode/Swift with 3 rounded buttons detached from the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'd like to create a tab bar that isn't really a tab bar. It would work like a tab bar in the way that it would send the user to other pages when clicking on it and it would always be present but the design would be different.

I would like it to be 3 buttons detached from the bottom of the screen unlike regular iOS tab bars and the button would be 3 circles with icons in it.
Is it possible to do such a thing in iOS, or does all apps really have to follow apple's standards?

[image: Example]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Upload the image to imgur.com and include the link. someone can edit it in for you.

Comment: true, thanks for the advice, here's the link to what I want to do http://imgur.com/YdoxqQu

Comment: Feel free to experiment with your own custom UI.  Not required to blindly follow Apple's UI guidelines.

Comment: If only I knew how, it seems I can't do such a thing using a tab bar controller, what's the other options ?

Comment: i manage to create `tabbar` like that but button upper part is not click able ..